# XML Parsing in Android Programming

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I am new to Android Programming, I had also asked this question before but didn't got quite satisfactory answers.

I need to implement parsing in my particular application. Can any body demistify the Parsing regarding the simple parsing of an XML String with an appropriate example.

Hoping I could get something vital this time.

Thanks,
david

Answer (score 1):

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
ListView list;
MyAdapter listadapter;
ArrayList<String> names=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> addresses=new ArrayList<String>();
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf;
DocumentBuilder db;
Document doc;
String value;
Context cxt;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listid);
    cxt=this;
    try {
        InputStream is=getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.events);
        dbf=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        db=dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc=db.parse(is,null);

     NodeList main_nl=doc.getElementsByTagName("event");

        for(int i=0;i<main_nl.getLength();i++){

            Node st_node=main_nl.item(i);
            NodeList sub_nl=st_node.getChildNodes();

            for(int j=0;j<sub_nl.getLength();j++){

                Node sub_node=sub_nl.item(j);

                String name=sub_node.getNodeName();

                if(name.equals("ename")){
                    value=sub_node.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                    names.add(value);

                }
                else if(name.equals("address")){
                    value=sub_node.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                    addresses.add(value);

                }
            }
        }
    }

     catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("XML Parsing Excpetion = " + e);
    }
    listadapter=new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(),names,addresses);
    list.setAdapter(listadapter);

    }         }
```

---

MyAdapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
LayoutInflater inflater;
ArrayList<String> namess;
ArrayList<String> addressess;


public MyAdapter(Context c) {
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
con = c;
}

public MyAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<String> names,
        ArrayList<String> addresses) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

namess= null;
this.addressess=null;
con=c;
this.addressess=addresses;
this.namess=names;
inflater = (LayoutInflater)con.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public int getCount()  
{
    return namess.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

   public static class ViewHolder
   {
    public TextView nam;
    public TextView add;

     }

   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{

        View v=convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        try
        {
    if (convertView == null) 
    {
        v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem,parent,false);
         holder=new ViewHolder();

         holder.nam=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.name);
         holder.add = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.address);

         v.setTag(holder);          
    }

         else{
         holder=(ViewHolder)v.getTag();
         }
            holder.nam.setText(namess.get(position).toString());
            holder.add.setText(addressess.get(position).toString());

        }
    catch(OutOfMemoryError e)
    {
        System.gc();

    }

    return v;
} 

private Context con;

   }
```

---

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"  >

<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/listid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</ListView>
```

listitem.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

   <TextView android:id="@+id/address"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

create floder raw. In that create an events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<events>
<event>
<ename>Network Connect Grow</ename>
<address>Panera Bread, Orlando, Fl</address>
</event>

<event>
<ename>SRB Networking Meeting</ename>
  <address>Mimi’s Café, Orlando, Fl</address>
</event>

</events>
```

Comment: thanx for posting this, i am going to implement this :)